# "Django not found" using venv in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: django, eclipse, virtualenv, pydev, python-venv

I'm not sure whether including `python3.6/site-packages` to the system pythonpath when setting up a PyDev workspace is correct.

I'm using Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers (version 2018-12 4.10.0) with PyDev to use Django 2.1.5 from a virtual environment, on Ubuntu 18.04.

**Main steps leading to the issue**

1. Set up the virtual env with:  `python3 -m venv djvenv`
2. Activate the venv in shell:  `source djvenv/bin/activate`
3. Install and test `Django~=2.1.5` from `requirements.txt` using commands `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `django-admin --version` (returns `2.1.5`)
4. In Eclipse, create a new workspace in directory `workspace`.
5. Set the Python interpreter to match the one from the virtual environment in directory `djvenv` via `Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter>` (set interpreter name to e.g. `python3-djenv` and interpreter path to: `/home/<username>/dj-workspace/djvenv/bin/python3`), and accept.
6. In the next prompt, tick the box to include the `python3.6/site-packages` directory to SYSTEM pythonpath. Click OK, then Apply and close

[image: tick site-packages when prompted]

Omitting to include the site-packages directory will result in a `"Django not found."` message when creating a Django project with `File>New>Project>PyDev>PyDev Django Project`.

[image: Django not found image]

Is it correct to include `python3.6/site-packages` here?

What bothers me is that it is specific to my project, while PyDev warns, in all caps:

> “IMPORTANT: The folders for your PROJECTS should not be added here,
>   but in your project configuration.”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct and that folder should be added...

-- what it means when it says that some file/folder is specific to your project is that files you're going to edit yourself should not be added under that configuration, and should be only added as a source folder in your own project.